# After Windows 8.1 Update, Whatsapp is not notifying

Tags: whatsapp

I updated my Lumia 520 yesterday to Windows 8.1, everything's cool, love the new features, I've checked I have all the alerts, volume and stuff properly set.

When I am using other apps, I don't get notifications from Whatsapp, nor when the phone is locked. If I want to check the new messages on whatsapp I have to open the app. It is not even showing the number of new messages at the tile.

I'm using Wifi, I'm not using Cellular data plan, what could be the problem? I already rebooted my phone several times :/

Comment: Have you allowed your phone to 'run application in background'..for that go to battery saver..select the app..and turn on the option to run in background.

Comment: I went there, I see that WhatsApp says ALLOWED in gray below the usage bars :(

Comment: Can you turn on option to run in background when battery saver is on..too..then check(always allowed)

Comment: It is set that way, Rebooted and still not working. Do you have also Windows Phone 8.1 and it is working for you?

Comment: Yes..its working for me.it may be work after reinstall the app.try it

Comment: Your WhatsApp version?

Comment: Ok, I might be reinstalling the app right now. The version I have is 2.11.596

Comment: Ah.ur version is up to date.after reinstall the problem exist..then check ur "notification+actions" option in ettings too.select the app and turn on notification banners and action center.

Comment: Ok, I reainstalled and soft-reboot, but... it is the same, it's not notifying me in any way unless I open whatsapp myself

Comment: Check ur notification+action setting

Comment: I uploaded my settings as screentshots to my OneDrive, check my settings here https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=75A67F174C15BE38!5533&authkey=!AKc7dGwIB1X0mIQ&ithint=folder%2c

Comment: The issue you're having relates to Push Notifications, it's nothing to do with running in the background. Do any other apps like Facebook or Twitter get notifications? and try using your cellular data, some wifi setups can block notifications.

Comment: But it worked with windows 8, why did it stop working when it updated to 8.1?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've solved it. It's pretty simple.

Whatsapp (at least on Windows) gets confused when you have your CELLULAR DATA ON and your Wifi ON.

So... If you're at home using WiFi and you don't have an active Data Plan, turn it off! Yes, just go to Settings -> Cellular -SIM and turn it Off if you don't have an active Data Plan.

After that, Whatsapp is gonna get all the notifications from the WiFi network, not from a non existing Data plan ;D

Hope it helped

Comment: Not doubting the answer, I'm sure it worked...but this sounds weird simply because I have wifi and cellular data turned on most times, and I still get notifications.

Comment: You get notifications because you have an active data plan. I didn't have any data plan active. That might be the reason