# Does whatsapp download messages in background or when app is opened

Tags: whatsapp, background-tasks

As far as I know, Windows Phone Doesn't notify you when it uses data. How can I tell if Whatsapp downloads messages in background or only when app is opened?
If it is doing in background than how it is achieving it 
P.S i am using Wp8.1 Dev preview with all latest updates

Comment: What version of the OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the app can behave of the both ways: If you use WP8.1, go to battery saver app and see if what'sapp is allowed to run in background. If yes, well, the app is downloading messages in background. A good way to notice that is paying attention to your notifications (do you receive what'sapp notification even if the app are not in the foreground?)
If the app are not allowed to run in background, when you open it, it will download all the messages send to you since the last time you opened it.

Skipping the obvious stuff, you can check the [official WhatsApp FAQ page](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/posts/9018/edit) with more informations regarding WhatsApp for Windows Phone.

Also, there are some reports that [WhatsApp can misbehave if Wifi and Mobile data network are activated at the same time](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/6218/after-windows-8-1-update-whatsapp-is-not-notifying)

Comment: Source for this? My phone seems to *always* download messages after I open the app. (And yes, it may run in the background, etc. etc.)

Comment: @Shawn please, see the edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, WhatsApp downloads messages in background. You can notice that the app gives notifications for messages even when you haven't opened the app.

In cases you have activated battery saver, WhatsApp doesn't run in the background, unless you have configured it to give notifications (this rarely happens). You can notice that there is no notifications arriving until you open the app.

This is supposed to be how it works. But, I frequently encounter a problem with the app when, even with battery-saver mode off, I don't get messages until I open the app. Most of the times WhatsApp notified that an error has occurred, and that I need to restart the phone to get notifications. I don't know whether it is a bug with the app or the OS.

I have also noticed (many of us might have noticed too) another problem with notifications. It doesn't show all the notifications. I mean it skips a handful of notifications about messages.

Comment: The app giving notifications even when it's not open has nothing to do with whether or not it downloads messages in the background. Also, what do you mean by `this rarely happens`? I have many apps set to run in the background even when Battery Saver is on.

Comment: As far as I know, WhatsApp gives notifications only for new messages, and if it doesn't run in the background, how could it download new messages (and give notifications) ?? So, I am 99% sure that the app hiving notification has everything to do with whether or not it downloads messages in the background. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I was referring to my experience. Of all the Lumia users I have met, only 2% set apps (especially like WhatsApp - most used app) to run I the background during battery saver mode, since WhatsApp is of continuous use and would drain their charges to fade the effectiveness of battery-saver mode. Not sure about people I never met though. 

Comment: Its called Push Notifications and has nothing to do with background processing.